# Ubuntu Touch "Saucy" or other no boot exclude "Quantal"

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, compiling

I build sources for my device. Then I download saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip. But its no boot. I tried all and work only MWC demo ZIP.

It was said that it is "hybris" problems. I tried build with new "hybris". But no difference. Now MWC demo no booting.

Whats me need do?
I tried on 3 phones.
Sony Xperia Z and Acro S and LG Optimus Black.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is a little intransparent (for me at least) right now, with the "flipped container" images for officially supported devices (Nexus) and still the "unflipped container" images for devices not officialy supported ("Ports").

So this is just a guess.

I think that the *-touch-armhf.zip files are the flipped images to be used only with Nexus devices.

You're looking for the *-phablet-armhf.zip for "unflipped" images available from [1], though the files are no longer updated apparently. And they had a broken sources.list setup at some point in time, missing the unity-next PPA, but maybe this is fixed in the 20130712 image. However they definitely still work with ports.

Until the new porting guide is made public (it was supposed to be done by the end of last week, then at the end of this week, now I wonder if it might be done next week?) that tells us how to port Ubuntu Touch to devices using the "flipped" container model, all you can do is flash an old "unflipped" image, fix the sources.list config, then apt-get update / dist-upgrade to the latest packages.

[1] http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/20130712/

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: Ok. Tried "unflipped" images. Still no boot. And "logcat" small. And no contain needed information.